# String is like :"Ðàäèî "Ìèð" - Ïåðâîå Äîáðîå Ðàäèî" how to decode it?

Tags: java, android, string, decode

String in icy-name is like :`"Ðàäèî "Ìèð" - Ïåðâîå Äîáðîå Ðàäèî"` (seems it is russian language) how to decode it?

Comment: no, it is not cyrillic

Comment: It seems the encoding you are using is not correct

Comment: Where, and how, is this string read from? It looks like it is read wrongly from the start. Also, a `String` has no encoding.

Comment: Decode as what you encode. But make sure you are encoding with the right char set.

Comment: `(seems it is russian language)` **NO**, it isn't.

Comment: Text is cyrillic "Радио "Мир" - Первое Доброе Радио" but in wrong encoding. Looks like a Unicode variant, but I cannot say exactly until I see the string in hexadecimal codes. Could you provide it please?

Comment: @AlexanderZhak Alex, I already found solution it's below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution:

```
public static String convertFromUTF8(String s) {
        String out = null;
        try {
            out = new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "windows-1251");
        } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: You have a more fundamental problem than that, as I mentioned in the comments. Also, this method is lossy.

Comment: Indeed, its win1251 in Latin 1 encoding, you're right